Octave: Unable to install/update packages
Operating system is Windows 10, octave version is 9.1.0
I have an octave package saved in C:\Users\me\Documents\OctavePackages
When I try to install the package from the command line with pkg install, I get this error:
>> pkg install control-4.0.1.tar.gz
The system cannot find the path specified.
error: unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 1
error: called from
    unpack at line 287 column 5
    untar at line 48 column 5
    install at line 99 column 9
    pkg at line 619 column 9

pkg update gives the same error, though I am able to load installed packages
moving the file to a folder contained in octave's path does not solve the issue
My best guess is that there is some permissions issue, but running octave as administrator does not solve the issue; I am lost on what to try next. This is a fresh installation of octave.
Edit:
I am also encountering the path-not-found error when calling the help command:
help sum
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
warning: help: Texinfo formatting filter exited abnormally; raw Texinfo source of help text follows
'sum' is a built-in function... (etc)

this error does not seem consistent in this context, I don't know what is causing it

do you have any non-ascii characters in you profile name / path, or in your octave installation path (through which method did you install octave)?

No, I have no non-ASCII chars in my profile name or my octave path. I used the windows octave installer with default settings, installation is in C:/Program Files/Gnu Octave

i would recommend posting this over at the octave support forum at https://octave.discourse.group, as they may be able to walk through other troubleshooting steps

I have done so, thanks for recommendation
